# How to move files with similar filename into new folder in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of files like this in the images folder.

[image]

and How can I create a new folder if there are multiple files with a similar name and move those similar files to that folder?

I am new to python.

Here is my expectation:

[image]

Comment: You can use the [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) package to create directories and move files.  You may also consider using the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) package to determine which files need to be moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
import glob
from pathlib import Path


for fn in Path("Images").glob("*"):
    file_base_name = "_".join(fn.stem.split("_")[:-1])
    file_count = len(glob.glob1("Images", f"{file_base_name}*"))
    if file_count > 1 or Path(file_base_name).is_dir():
        outdir = Path("Images") / file_base_name
        outdir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
        fn.rename(outdir / fn.name)
```

**Input:**
[image: input_img]

**Output:**
[image: output_img]

> ### Please ignore file names extension. I create those just to test my code

Answer (score 0):

In this case you don't even need re:

```py
from pathlib import Path
for fn in Path("Images").glob("*.jpg"):
    outdir = Path("Images") / "_".join(fn.stem.split("_")[:-1])
    outdir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
    fn.rename(outdir / fn.name)
```

What's going on here?

[`Pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is how you want to think of paths if you can.  It combines most of the `os.path` apis.  Specifically:

- glob gets us all the files matching the glob in the path
- mkdir makes the directory (only if it doesn't exist)
- rename moves the file there

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to test since I don't have your files. My suggestion would be to comment out the `mkdir` command and the `shutil.move` command and replace them with print statements to see what commands would be generated before letting it run for real. But I think it should work.

```py
import pathlib
import os
import re
from itertools import groupby
import shutil

source_dir = 'Images'

files = [os.path.basename(f) for f in pathlib.Path(source_dir).glob('*.jpg')]

def keyfunc(file):
    m = re.match('^(.*?)_\d+.jpg$', file)
    return m[1]

matched_files = [file for file in files if re.search(r'_\d+.jpg$', file)]
matched_files.sort()
for k, g in groupby(matched_files, keyfunc):
    new_dir = os.path.join(source_dir, k)
    if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
        os.mkdir(new_dir)
    for file in g:
         shutil.move(os.path.join(source_dir, file), new_dir)
```